# Some people or Many people!

Tags: quantifiers

In an English training book published by Oxford University, there's a conversation containing the line below:

> Look, there's a building with *many/some* people outside. Turn left before you get there.

The provided answer is ***some*** which confuses me a lot. Why can't it be ***many people***?

Comment: Hello. Pacen. It's a matter of what sounds more natural, not which is grammatical (both are). 'A lot of' or 'lots of', say,  would be used instead of 'many' here in conversation.

Comment: It can.  "Many" would imply a crowd of people, though, which might not fit the intended meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: As I've pointed out before, _many_ and _much_ are constrained in their appearance; try adding a negative and see what happens. They're not quite NPIs, but they're more comfortable in negative environments.

Comment: Ask the grammar Nazis. They will come up with some reason why "some" is correct and "many" is wrong. I think they are kind of people (I forgot the word) who like to inflict and receive pain.

Comment: @Peter (1) As John Lawler says, this has been addressed before. But it looks like it would take a lot of time to find duplicates. (2) While 'Accumulation' has echoed what I've said, they also don't add supporting evidence, making for an inadequate 'answer' as I see it.

Answer (score 2):

"Many" sounds more natural to me when it's used as a subject (or subject complement) rather than an object. When an object is needed, it feels more natural to use other phrases such as "a lot of" or "a bunch of". I find it odd to be testing students on this, though. It's hardly grammatically incorrect to use "many" in an object, and the feeling of unnaturalness is more of feeling stilted and overly formal rather than "wrong". "a lot of" and "a bunch of", on the other hand, feel more natural, but also more colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

> We use many to refer to a large number of something countable. We most commonly use it in questions and in negative sentences:
>
> - Were there **many** children at the party?
> - I **don’t** have **many** relatives. We’re a small family.
>
> We don’t normally use many alone before a noun in an affirmative statement:
>
> There were **a lot of** people at the swimming pool this morning.
>
> Not: <s>There were many people</s> …
>
> <sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

*Many* grammar books at intermediate level will have learners believe that "[many](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/many)" is **preferred in question forms** and **in negatives**.

*“How many people are in front of that building?”*
*“There aren't many.”*

But a native speaker could also respond with the more informal
“*There's some*” and “*Not a lot*.”

Arguing that “some” is the best choice because the noun *building* is preceded by the indefinite article is mistaken. Here are *some* examples with *many* in affirmative sentences:

> *Look, there's* **a** *car park* (US *parking lot*) **with many** *parking spaces.*
> *Here's **a book** with **many** black and white photos.*
> I want [**a house** with **many**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20house%20with%20many%22&biw=1141&bih=637&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsbQNuHxOWZOazSwE2xdFw3sRZFfSg%3A1664202866366&ei=crgxY9b7Ff2Dxc8PvLaN2AM&ved=0ahUKEwjW_Lvl1rL6AhX9QfEDHTxbAzsQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22a%20house%20with%20many%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BAghEApQ7QtYsiZgii9oAHAAeACAAWiIAcUGkgEDOS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) rooms.

If the number of available parking spots, photos, or rooms were fewer then the determiner *some* would make a better fit.

So the answer is both determiners are *grammatical*, which one depends on the information the speaker/writer wants to convey. In everyday conversation, saying a ***building with some people outside*** is more natural because…

> *A lot of' or 'lots of', say, would be used instead of 'many' here in conversation.* @Edwin Ashworth

See also: [Is 'many' used in positive sentences or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165988/is-many-used-in-positive-sentences-or-not)